# TF frames order, which should be fixed and which should be the parent and child?

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, ros-kinetic, base-footprint

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Mobile robot moving around static known map. Map was built with hector SLAM.

Is that the right order for the frame tree?

Do I need the base_footprint?

Fixed fram Odom
Tree
--> odom --> base_link --> laser --> map

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/309001/tf-frames-order,-which-should-be-fixed-and-which-should-be-the-parent-and-child?/) by [karimemara17](https://answers.ros.org/users/38280/karimemara17/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2018-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should have a look at the different REP related to frames : [REP 103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html), [REP 105](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html) and [REP 120](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0120.html).

The standard tf tree in your case looks like : map -> odom -> base_link -> laser. Map should be at the top of the tf tree since it's the world frame.

It's not required to have the `base_footprint`, it's just the `base_link` frame with z=0, you are free to create it or not.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karimemara17](https://answers.ros.org/users/38280/karimemara17/) on 2018-11-21**:
And in RVIZ the map should be the fixed frame? So when I estimate the pose and give it the goal it be on the map right?

I will take a look at the different REP and will update the question.
Thank you for help!

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-11-21**:
The fixed frame is mostly for visualization purpose you could even set it on a wheel (eventhough it's stupid).
Do you talk about 2D pose estimate and 2D nav goal in `rviz` ? If so then it will be according to the fixed frame of `rviz`, that's why it's better to set `map` as the fixed frame.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-11-21**:
If not then it's up to you to define the reference frame_id when giving a goal (which sould be `map`).

**Comment by [karimemara17](https://answers.ros.org/users/38280/karimemara17/) on 2018-11-21**:
Yes it I was talking about the 2D pose estimate and 2D nav goal in rviz. I did all that and set the frames in the order you suggested and it still doesn't want to move. It does this when estimating the 2D pose
(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AKhtZoMIMrkTengJJV6RVGA-c4bFaosM/view?usp=sharing))

**Comment by [karimemara17](https://answers.ros.org/users/38280/karimemara17/) on 2018-11-21**:
Also I should mention that I'm running rviz and navigation stake on a pc while the lidar and the base are on Raspberry Pi over network.

I also tried roswtf and I gave me an error something like
**ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't**
GlobalCostmapFootprint --> localCM footprint

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-11-22**:
The behavior in your video is very strange, I would suggest you to create a new question for this describing everything you do that result to this (the move_base config, the launch files and the commands you run for example).

**Comment by [karimemara17](https://answers.ros.org/users/38280/karimemara17/) on 2018-11-22**:
Thank you again, and yes I just posted the question: https://answers.ros.org/question/309152/strange-behavior-between-move_base-navigation-stack-and-rviz/